# Opening url in Browser with proxy

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, proxy

i have a proxylist and want to open a specified URL in browser, for example chrome or firefox multiple times. Each session should use a new proxy from the list. The Browser should just stay open. Are there any APIs for opeing links with proxy?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Proxy settings are on runtime level of your application (in this case it is a browser application). With JS you can ask through a proxy but you can't change browsers proxy settings.

If it would be possible I could host a web page where you could click a link for example to a bank but your transfer would go through my proxy so I could read all data you send and receive.

Comment: but there must be a way to give the proxy IP:Port as parameters to the browser on opening

Comment: You can do it only under your operating system. For example you can run your chrome with environment variable. It is dependant on your operating system and browser, in windows you can configure your proxy inside of chrome or firefox. Under Linuks you can set env vars with export HTTP_PROXY=youraddress, export HTTPS_PROXY=youraddressofproxy and then run google-chrome. Firefox under linuks has same settings as windows version does.

Comment: but i need to open every new browser window on a new proxy

Comment: no idea how about windows version of browsers but on Linux you can run every application with its own environment variables. However you will also need to isolate temporary files of a browser. Quick example for chrome:

   ` $> all_proxy=yourProxy.host google-chrome --some-flag-to-point=tmp-dir-for-this-instance`

you can consider also looking for some browser extension for managing multiple proxies, like that https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/proxy-switchysharp/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm